# Make Text Field item as Read Only in APEX 5.0

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I have some text field page items on my APEX 5.0  page and I want to make the textboxes as read only/non-editable. During the page load I want to use these text boxes for only the data display on the page and should be non-editable.
Can somebody advice on how to do that? What attributes need to set for this?

Comment: Please post any comment if you find any solution

Comment: @SebriZouhaier I found a solution and posted it as a new answer (yes 5 years later).

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit late to the party, but I found myself confronted to this problem and I wanted to share the solution I came up with.

In fact you just need to create your item as a text area, let say `P1_Text_Area` and you give it a `readonly` attribute using JavaScript. Write thoses 2 lines in the "Function and Global Variable Declaration" of your page:

```
var disItem = document.getElementById('P1_Text_Area');
disItem.readOnly = true;
```

Hope this helps someone in need.

Answer (score 0):

in item properties find the

**Read Only** group

and set **Read Only Condition Type** as **Always**

or the option that suits to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use  disabled + save session state ==> read only

[image]